# Can't set attributes on instance of "object" class

Tags: python, attributes, language-design

So, I was playing around with Python while answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528932/how-to-create-inline-objects-with-properties-in-python/), and I discovered that this is not valid:

```
o = object()
o.attr = 'hello'
```

due to an `AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'attr'`. However, with any class inherited from object, it is valid:

```
class Sub(object):
    pass

s = Sub()
s.attr = 'hello'
```

Printing `s.attr` displays 'hello' as expected. Why is this the case? What in the Python language specification specifies that you can't assign attributes to vanilla objects?

---

<sub>For other workarounds, see [How can I create an object and add attributes to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827623).</sub>

Comment: Pure guesswork: The `object` type is immutable and new attributes cannot be added? This seems like it would make the most sense.

Comment: @ S.Lott: See the very first line of this question. Purely curiosity.

Comment: Your title is misleading, you are trying to set attributes on `object` class instances, not on `object` class.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

To support arbitrary attribute assignment, an object needs a `__dict__`: a dict associated with the object, where arbitrary attributes can be stored. Otherwise, there's nowhere to *put* new attributes.

An instance of `object` does **not** carry around a `__dict__` -- if it did, before the horrible circular dependence problem (since `dict`, like most everything else, inherits from `object`;-), this would saddle *every* object in Python with a dict, which would mean an overhead of *many* bytes per object that currently doesn't have or need a dict (essentially, all objects that don't have arbitrarily assignable attributes don't have or need a dict).

For example, using the excellent `pympler` project (you can get it via svn from [here](http://code.google.com/p/pympler/source/checkout)), we can do some measurements...:

```
>>> from pympler import asizeof
>>> asizeof.asizeof({})
144
>>> asizeof.asizeof(23)
16
```

You wouldn't want every `int` to take up 144 bytes instead of just 16, right?-)

Now, when you make a class (inheriting from whatever), things change...:

```
>>> class dint(int): pass
... 
>>> asizeof.asizeof(dint(23))
184
```

...the `__dict__` *is* now added (plus, a little more overhead) -- so a `dint` instance can have arbitrary attributes, but you pay quite a space cost for that flexibility.

So what if you wanted `int`s with just *one* extra attribute `foobar`...? It's a rare need, but Python does offer a special mechanism for the purpose...

```
>>> class fint(int):
...   __slots__ = 'foobar',
...   def __init__(self, x): self.foobar=x+100
... 
>>> asizeof.asizeof(fint(23))
80
```

...not *quite* as tiny as an `int`, mind you! (or even the two `int`s, one the `self` and one the `self.foobar` -- the second one can be reassigned), but surely much better than a `dint`.

When the class has the `__slots__` special attribute (a sequence of strings), then the `class` statement (more precisely, the default metaclass, `type`) does **not** equip every instance of that class with a `__dict__` (and therefore the ability to have arbitrary attributes), just a finite, rigid set of "slots" (basically places which can each hold one reference to some object) with the given names.

In exchange for the lost flexibility, you gain a lot of bytes per instance (probably meaningful only if you have zillions of instances gallivanting around, but, there *are* use cases for that).

Comment: This explains how the mechanism is implemented but does not explain why is it implemented in this way. I can think of at least two or three ways to implement adding __dict__ on the fly which will not have the overhead downside but will add some simplicity.

Comment: Note that non-empty `__slots__` do not work with variable-length types such as  `str`, `tuple`, and in Python 3 also `int`.

Comment: Nice and thanks! [If an object doesn't have `__dict__`, does its class must have a `__slot__` attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46575174/156458)

Comment: It's a great explanation, but still doesn't answer why (or how) `Sub` has the `__dict__` attribute and object doesn't, being that `Sub` inherit from `object`, how is that attribute (and others like `__module__`) added in the inheritance? May be this could be a new question

Comment: An object's `__dict__` is only created the first time it's needed, so the memory cost situation isn't quite as simple as the `asizeof` output makes it look. (`asizeof` doesn't know how to avoid `__dict__` materialization.) You can see the dict not getting materialized until needed in [this example](https://ideone.com/xVKqMC), and you can see one of the code paths responsible for `__dict__` materialization [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.2/Objects/dictobject.c#L4288).

Answer (score 18):

As other answerers have said, an `object` does not have a `__dict__`. `object` is the base class of **all** types, including `int` or `str`. Thus whatever is provided by `object` will be a burden to them as well. Even something as simple as an *optional* `__dict__` would need an extra pointer for each value; this would waste additional 4-8 bytes of memory for each object in the system, for a very limited utility.

---

Instead of doing an instance of a dummy class, in Python 3.3+, you can (and should) use [`types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) for this.

Answer (score 4):

It is simply due to optimization.

Dicts are relatively large.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof((lambda:1).__dict__)
140
```

Most (maybe all) classes that are defined in C do not have a dict for optimization.

If you look at the [source code](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/object.c?revision=74457&view=markup) you will see that there are many checks to see if the object has a dict or not.

Answer (score 2):

So, investigating my own question, I discovered this about the Python language: you can inherit from things like int, and you see the same behaviour:

```
>>> class MyInt(int):
       pass

>>> x = MyInt()
>>> print x
0
>>> x.hello = 4
>>> print x.hello
4
>>> x = x + 1
>>> print x
1
>>> print x.hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'hello'
```

I assume the error at the end is because the add function returns an int, so I'd have to override functions like `__add__` and such in order to retain my custom attributes. But this all now makes sense to me (I think), when I think of "object" like "int".

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object :

> **Note**: [`object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object) does *not* have a [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__), so you can’t assign arbitrary attributes to an instance of the [`object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object) class.

Answer (score 0):

It's because object is a "type", not a class. In general, all classes that are defined in C extensions (like all the built in datatypes, and stuff like numpy arrays) do not allow addition of arbitrary attributes.

Comment: But object() is an object, just like Sub() is an object. My understanding is that both s and o are objects. So what is the fundamental difference between s and o? Is it that one is an instantiated type and the other is an instantiated class?

Comment: Bingo. That's exactly the issue.

Comment: In Python 3, the difference between types and classes doesn't really exist. So "type" & "class" are now fairly synonymous. But you still can't add attributes to those classes that don't have a `__dict__`, for the reasons given by Alex Martelli.

Answer (score -2):

This is (IMO) one of the fundamental limitations with Python - you can't re-open classes. I believe the actual problem, though, is caused by the fact that classes implemented in C can't be modified at runtime... subclasses can, but not the base classes.