# Can't set attributes on ElementTree.Element instance in Python 3

Tags: python, elementtree

I don't understand why in Python 3 I can't add some attributes to `ElementTree.Element` instances. Here is the difference:

In Python 2:

```python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jun 18 2012, 14:18:47) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> el = ET.Element('table')
>>> el.foo = 50
>>> el.foo
50
>>>
```

In Python 3:

```python
Python 3.3.0 (default, Sep 11 2013, 16:29:08) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> el = ET.Element('table')
>>> el.foo = 50
>>> el.foo
AttributeError: foo
>>>
```

Python 2 is provided by a distribution (CentOS). Python 3 was compiled from sources.

Is it intended behavior, a bug, or do I have to recompile python 3 with some additional flags?

**UPDATE**:

Some clarification: I am trying to set attributes on Python object, i.e. on `Element` instance. Not XML attributes (`Element.attrib`).

This issue actually arose when I tried to subclass `Element`. Here is example:

```python
>>> class Table(ET.Element):
...     def __init__(self):
...         super().__init__('table')
...         print('calling __init__')
...         self.foo = 50
... 
>>> t = Table()
calling __init__
>>> t.foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'foo'
>>>
```

This makes me think that `Element` class is instantiated in some tricky way, but I can't figure out what goes on. Hence the question.

Comment: i'm not using python 3 (still on 2) but can you try dumping t.__dict__ and see if foo is even in there?

Comment: again: see the first link in my answer, and please check whether the python 3 object returned has a `__dict__` attribute (and possibly equivalently, if it has a `__slots__` attribute). Using `__slots__` leads to much better memory performance, but has the side effect that you can't add attributes the normal way (and since etree is [was] a memory hog, this is exactly what i'd expect them to do). If it _does_ have slots, you just need to declare them in your object as well, with a `__slots__` declaration for the new fields you want, and then it should work. (if that's the problem..)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably intentional... take a look at [Can't set attributes of object class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529002/cant-set-attributes-of-object-class) . If they *haven't* enhanced ElementTree to use slots instead of dict in that time, i would be surprised anyways.

Not clear what you are trying to do... are you really trying to set *python* attributes, or *XML* attributes? If the latter, you really want to do this:

```
el = ET.Element('table')
el.set('foo', 50) 
#or
el.attrib['foo'] = 50
```

If you really want to add python attributes, you should subclass instead, and probably provide your own Element/SubElement functions to supply the 'wrapped' elements instead of standard ones.

Update 6/4/2016: Maybe not clear from my answer, but here's what you probably need to do (I'm normally python 2.7):

```
class Table(ET.Element):
    # Adding __slots__ gives it a known attribute to use    
    __slots__ = ('foo',)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('table')
        print('calling __init__')
        self.foo = 50
```

Comment: See update to my question. I try to set attributes on python object, not XML attributes. And I tried to subclass ``Element``, this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Since 3.3 ElementTree tries to import the c implementation in for efficiency, however you can't set arbitrary attributes on that implementation.  If you are in a situation where you don't want to use the Set or Get methods every time, you should use ET._Element_Py, which is the Python implementation.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.attrib), it seems that the only way to go is now:

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> el = ET.Element('table')
>>> el.set("foo", 50)
>>> el.get("foo")
50
>>> el.attrib
{"foo": 50}
```

It worked under Python 2.X too but is probably mandatory now.

Also, [an interesting ticket in Python bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue17989) where they decided to change the exception message.