# Creating objects on the fly in Python

Tags: python

Why do I need

```
class DummyObject(object):
    pass
```

in order to make

```
dummy = DummyObject()
dummy.foo = 42
```

Why isn't this legal in Python?

```
dummy = object()
dummy.foo = 42
```

Which gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

Comment: Very good question but it seems it already has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529002/cant-set-attributes-of-object-class

Comment: As with many "why" questions about Python, the answer is "because Guido said so."

Comment: You could always do: `dummy = type('Dummy', (object,), {})()`