# Python: Assigning custom attributes on objects

Tags: python

When I try to assign custom attribute on `object` instance, `AttributeError` is raised:

```
>>> o = object()
>>> o.hi = 'mom'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'hi'
```

The same happens on most (all?) built-in types.

However, when I create instance of trivial `object` subclass, new property is succesfully created:

```
>>> class foobar(object): pass
... 
>>> o = foobar()
>>> o.hi = 'mom'
>>> o.hi
'mom'
```

Why is that happening? Should I make my classes reject custom attributes to match `object` behavior? If so, how could it be done?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1529002/1679863

Comment: I don't think you should because there isn't really a reason to, but to do that, do this: `def __getattribute__(self, attr): raise AttributeError("{} object has no attribute {}".format(repr(self.__class__.__name__), repr(attr)))`

Comment: *"Should I make my classes reject custom attributes to match object behavior?"* - well, do you need to?