# Efficiently accessing indices: is storing indices in a dict the fastest way?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of tuples that I need to access the index of repeatedly. Is the fastest way to do this to store the tuples and their indices in a dict? Or is there a better way?

Given a tuple that exists in an ordered list of tuples, I need to access the index of it efficiently. I can think of two ways to do it; call `.index` on the list, or store the tuples as keys in a dictionary with the index as their value and look up the index by doing a dictionary lookup.

```
order = list(itertools.product(range(4),repeat=6))
%timeit order.index(random.choice(order))
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 35 µs per loop

order_dic = {i:order.index(i) for i in order}
%timeit order_dic[random.choice(order)]
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 443 ns per loop
```

Comment: Are the indexes sequential numbers? Then use a list, otherwise a dict.

Comment: @poke I'm not sure what you're asking. They're indices, so they have to be sequential. Calling `.index` on a list is somewhat inefficient, though, and performing a dict lookup is faster.

Comment: `list.index()` *searches* the list for a value, it’s not an index lookup. So you are comparing two very different things here. Please show what you’re actually trying to do; I can’t tell from your question.

Comment: @poke Given a tuple, I need to find out what its index is. I've explained it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost always, the second option will be faster. This is because in the first example, you search the list in order to find the index, an *O(n)* operation on lists. Whereas in the second example, you lookup a value in the dictionary, which is *O(1)* on average.

However, space is something to consider here as the second option has the overhead of an additional dict. In Brandon Rhodes's [talk](http://pyvideo.org/video/2571/all-your-ducks-in-a-row-data-structures-in-the-s) at Pycon 2014, he says that dicts tend to use *3 to 4 times* more space than they need, so that adding new elements is still fast, which could be a lot of overhead if you have a large list of tuples.

If list of tuples you use as an example is actually the list you are searching through, then there is a fast and memory-efficient way to *calculate* the index of a given tuple, relying on the way `itertools.product` works:

```
a[5] + a[4] >> 2 + a[3] >> 4 + a[2] >> 6 + a[1] >> 8 + a[0] >> 10
```

This will give the index of tuple `a`. This is nearly as fast as the second option but does not have the additional space requirement of an extra dict.

(The idea behind this method is that the tuple is essentially a six-digit base-four number, and since `itertools.product` outputs them in order, this will give the index.)

Comment: Another interesting option is `from collections import namedtuple`, if the index is static. Not sure how the attribute lookup compares to the index lookup, though.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about calculating the indices based on the value using the properties of `itertools.product`; I might do that. Then again, the list of tuples I'm going to have isn't going to be terribly large (probably not more than a few thousand), so I might just stick with the dict lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it will be really hard to get any faster than a `dict()`. Just see how long `random.choice()` takes without any lookup:

```
>>> order = list(itertools.product(range(4),repeat=6))
>>> order_dic = {i:order.index(i) for i in order}

>>> %timeit order.index(random.choice(order))
>>> %timeit order_dic[random.choice(order)]
>>> %timeit random.choice(order)

10000 loops, best of 3: 98.6 µs per loop
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.6 µs per loop
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.39 µs per loop
```

So, the lookup consists mere 15% of the total you were measuring.

But maybe you could consider storing the index in the tuple? Or storing the tuple in another tuple, that also has the index? For example `order = list(enumerate(order))`.

You could assign the index to each tuple object:

```
order = list(itertools.product(range(4),repeat=6))
order_dic = {i:order.index(i) for i in order}

%timeit order.index(random.choice(order))
%timeit order_dic[random.choice(order)]
%timeit random.choice(order)

class mytuple(tuple): pass

order = list(map(mytuple, order))
for i, t in enumerate(order): t.rev_index = i

%timeit random.choice(order).rev_index

## -- End pasted text --
10000 loops, best of 3: 101 µs per loop
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.59 µs per loop
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 µs per loop
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.53 µs per loop
```

It's faster than the hash map.

You [can't set attributes of builtins dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1529002/1916449), so we have to subclass it. We also can't use `__slots__` because variable-size types like `tuple` don't support it, so every `mytuple` will have an additional `__dict__`. But apparently this still has a smaller memory footprint (almost twice) than using one `dict` to map all the indexes:

```
>>> from pympler.asizeof import asizeof
>>> asizeof(order_dic) \
... / (asizeof(order) - asizeof(list(itertools.product(range(4),repeat=6))))
1.8341168569509738
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the lookup time of `random.choice()` has to do with my question. Also, I'm not sure what `order = list(enumerate(order))` is supposed to do; given a tuple that I need to find the index of, I would still need to search through the list to find the tuple, same as `.index()`

Comment: @CactusWoman The `order = list(enumerate(order))` means that each element of of order will be a tuple with it's index in the list first and its value second, so you access the normal value with `a[1]` and then to get the index, you can simply use `a[0]` (for some element `a`).

Comment: Ok, now I get what you're saying. That could work for the question as I've described it (although for my implementation it won't work because I'll be generating the tuples separately and then looking them up)

Comment: @CactusWoman: See my updated answer. Maybe subclassing a tuple could work for you.