# Add property ad-hoc to object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to ad-hoc build up an object, something like:

```
b = object()
b.a = 0
```

But no, I can not add an `a` to `object b`. [It's explained here, why that happens. Mainly because object does not have a dict.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529002/cant-set-attributes-of-object-class)

**But**, is there a correct way to ad-hoc construct such an `object b`? Maybe instead of object a class that *can* take properties?

(Before you warn me or advise me to just build a class - yes, I'm aware that this might be the best way to do in many cases. But first, I think, there are cases where an ad-hoc object is useful, maybe just for lazyness in a small code. Second, I also want to understand what's behind the two cases `a` and `b`.)

Comment: Keep in mind that's the initializer, not the constructor.

Comment: I don't know the details, but there is definitely a bit more happening when you make something a `class`, including adding `__dict__` attribute (note: Python uses the term attribute instead of property; properties are a special type of attribute). Quote from the documentation: [Note: object does not have a __dict__, so you can’t assign arbitrary attributes to an instance of the object class.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object).

Comment: As for an (ugly) one-liner that doesn't use `class`, to quickly create a simple object: `b = type('MyClass', (object,), {})()`.

Comment: So...stuck in the old Stack Overflow problem: Question gets closed within minutes, but no one will ever re-open it, even though the problem was completely fixed. What should I do?