# Python Difference Between Setting attributes in object and by defining pass in a custom class

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have below code:

```
arg = object()
arg.abc = "abc_text"
print arg.abc
```

It throws error "AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'abc'"

But When the code is modified to below, it works:

```
class MyCustomClass(object):
    pass

arg = MyCustomClass()
arg.abc = "abc_text"
print arg.abc
```

What happened exactly I didn't understand at all. object is base for and class and I tried to set attribute. It should have worked. But it didn't. And what exactly happened when a custom class is called?

Comment: *"It should have worked"* - no, it shouldn't, that's why it didn't. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1529002/3001761

Comment: This is a very interesting question.  I'm glad you asked it (even if it was only to bring the dupe to my attention).

Comment: Ya, saw the other link. It's the same he asked. Didn't see it before! But I am not even clear with the ans over there. @mgilson , If you could ans it in a line or 2 in the comments here, would be helpful to me :)

Comment: @tdka -- The point is that to add an attribute to something, it needs to have a `__dict__` (to store the attributes in).  Instances of `object` don't have a `__dict__` (to save on memory) so you can't add attributes to instances of `object`.  Brushing aside the subtleties of `__slots__`, instances of `object` subclasses _do_ have a `__dict__` so you _can_add attributes.

Comment: @mgilson -- ya got it. Thanks. In addition to it, wanted to ask 1 more question. Is the base object immutable. can't we change any of its attributes?

Comment: @tdka -- The base object is a type ... and it looks like trying to set attributes on it lead to an explicit `TypeError`.  So that looks like it's explicitly disallowed (though I can't think of any reason why you would _want_ to do that :-)

Comment: @mgilson -- Thanks :) I actually had 15 attributes and wanted to set in a single object before passing into a different method. Hence the situation arrised and wanted to do this :)

Comment: If you are using a recent enough python version, `types.SimpleNamespace` should do the trick (IIRC).

Comment: Using 2.7 in the project.