# Which python classes allow assignment to not-yet-existent attributes, and which don't?

Tags: python

In Python, the `__dict__` of an instance seems to be "open" for some classes,  "closed" for others:

```
# "closed" type example:
x = object()
x.eggs = 'spam'   # raises an AttributeError
```

whereas:

```
# "open" type example I:
x = Exception()
x.eggs = 'spam'   # does not raise an AttributeError

# "open" type example II: subclasses
class thing(object): pass
x = thing()
x.eggs = 'spam'   # does not raise an AttributeError
```

I would like to understand where/how/why this difference in behaviour is implemented: why is `object` closed but `thing` open? Why is `Exception` open?  I have two reasons for the question:

- In pure Python, the only way I have found of replicating the "closed" behaviour is to implement `__setattr__` myself and raise the `AttributeError` in it, composing its appropriately-formatted error message by hand.  Is there a less-verbose, more-DRY way (and one which doesn't generate a potentially misleading backtrace to `__setattr__`)?
- In an IPC module I have written, I want to document an example of usage, and the most concise and universal way would be to find an example of a builtin `type` (failing that, one from the standard library) (a) which can be pickled and sent to another process, and (b) whose instances exhibit the "open" behaviour.  So far the best one I have found is `Exception` but that looks a little misleading in the documentation (people will think it's specifically about exceptions).  A more generic object would be nicer, but `object` is closed, and a subclass (like `thing` in the example above) is not `pickle`able unless you save its definition in a file on the path. Maybe there's a standard container somewhere that's open? The classics (`tuple/list/dict`) are all closed.

Comment: Built-ins (the *real* ones, i.e. those directly written in C) don't support attribute assignment. The point is: **builtins don't have a `__dict__`!**. For example: `object().__dict__ -> AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute '__dict__'`.

Comment: `x = object()` has no `__dict__`?

Comment: See [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots)

Comment: @Bakuriu I wondered about that, but I think the implementation of `Exception` is in C too.

Comment: You could try using `collections.namedtuple` ?

Comment: Also a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1529002/748858

Comment: As a mater of fact attribute assignment updates the module's namespace dictionary, for example `my_obj.sample_attr = 'my_value'` is equivalent to `my_obj.__dict__["sample_attr "] = 'my_value'`. Also note that class attribute assignments update the class’s dictionary, never the dictionary of a base class. Read more https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: @Kasramvd -- Well ... that's only true for objects that have a `__dict__`.  For objects that define `__slots__`, it is a little more tricky.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu  Thanks: understanding of `__slots__` is exactly what I was lacking (I somehow never heard of it in 8 years of Python).

Comment: @mgilson Yes exactly. Basically I think such adversative behaviors are not very correct and may cause some problems and confusions.

Comment: @GWW: `namedtuple` turns out not to be a `type`, it's a factory function.  Incidentally I found that Python 3.3+ has `types.SimpleNamespace` for exactly this purpose, but unfortunately that doesn't help as I want to support Python 2 as well.

Comment: @jez: The object returned by the namedtuple factory function has the `__dict__` attribute and you can add additional attributes after.  Perhaps the underlying type generated by the factory function can be used for your purposes.