# Why Does This Usage of a Class Work in Python?

Tags: python, class, instance

I run the following very trivial Python code. I am very surprised that it actually run. Could someone explain to me why I can even assign values to "nd" and "hel" without defining them in the class definition? Is this because the attribute can be added in the instance level?

```
class tempClass(object):

a = tempClass()
a.nd = 1
a.hel = 'wem3'
```

Comment: The way that objects were designed allows you to create attributes by assignment.  Try the same thing with a function (functions are objects):  define a function, ```f```, then add an attribute to it - ```f.new = 1``` - it works :).  ```...can be added in the instance level?``` attributes can be added to the class itself in the same manner.

Comment: Thank you, @wwii. Does it work adding a function, instead of an attribute, to an instance of a class? I tried it. It did not work. But maybe I did not do it the right way.

Comment: Define the function then assign the function name to the class or instance attribute.   ```def f(): print('1'); tempClass.foo = f```.

Comment: So I played around a bit and some objects don't allow that behaviour but classes and functions do.  There is a hint in the "User-defined functions" section of [3.2 The standard type hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) in the docs.

Comment: Thank you, @wwii. It works as you said.

Comment: The exact code pasted would not run at all, it has a basic syntax error.

Comment: @wwii see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529002/cant-set-attributes-of-object-class) to a SO question about why you can't assign to built-in types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has no notion of variable declaration, only assignments. The same applies to attributes: you simply assign an initial value to bring it into existence.

There is nothing special about the `__init__` method in this regard. For example,

```
class TempClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.nd = 1

a = tempClass()
a.hel = 'wem3'
```

Both attributes are created in the same way: by assigning a value to them. `__init__` is called when `a` is first created, but otherwise is not special. `self` inside `__init__` is a reference to the object referenced by `a`, so `self.nd = 1` is identical to `a.nd = 1`. After the object is created, `a.hel` is created and initialized with `'wem3'` by the same process.