# If an object doesn't have `__dict__`, must its class have a `__slots__` attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/1529099/156458

> To support arbitrary attribute assignment, an object needs a `__dict__`:
> a dict associated with the object, where arbitrary attributes can be
> stored. Otherwise, there's nowhere to put new attributes.
>
> An instance of `object` does not carry around a `__dict__` -- if it did,
> before the horrible circular dependence problem (since `__dict__`, like most
> everything else, inherits from `object`;-), this would saddle every
> object in Python with a dict, which would mean an overhead of many
> bytes per object that currently doesn't have or need a dict
> (essentially, all objects that don't have arbitrarily assignable
> attributes don't have or need a dict).

> ...

> When the class has the `__slots__` special attribute (a sequence of strings), then the `class` statement (more precisely, the default metaclass, `type`) does **not** equip every instance of that class with a `__dict__` (and therefore the ability to have arbitrary attributes), just a finite, rigid set of "slots" (basically places which can each hold one reference to some object) with the given names.

If an object doesn't have `__dict__`, must its class have a `__slots__` attribute?

For example, an instance of `object` doesn't have a `__dict__`:

```
>>> object().__dict__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

but it doesn't have `__slots__` either:

```
>>> object.__slots__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute '__slots__'
```

Do `object` instances have any attributes at all?

How many possibilities are there:

- an object has `__dict__`, and its class has `__dict__` but no `__slots__`
- an object doesn't have `__dict__`, and its class has `__slots__`
- an object doesn't have `__dict__`, and its class doesn't have `__slots__` ?

Is it possible to tell if an object has `__dict__` from its class?

- if its class has `__slots__`, then it doesn't have `__dict__`, correct?
- if its class doesn't have `__slots__`, how can I tell if it has `__dict__` or not?

Comment: It's refreshing to see a question that isn't homework once in a while.

Comment: Those rules don't necessarily apply to builtin classes or classes implemented in C in an extension module.

Comment: I think you just proved that no, a type is not required to have `__slots__` if it doesn't have a `__dict__`

Comment: Note that you can delete `__slots__` after class creation time.

Comment: @o11c: Eew, yeah, that adds a layer of potential misdirection to the whole deal.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For user defined classes (defined using the `class` keyword in regular Python code), a class will always have `__slots__` on the class, `__dict__` on the instance, or both (if one of the slots defined is `'__dict__'`, or one of the user defined classes in an inheritance chain defines `__slots__` and another one does not, creating `__dict__` implicitly). So that's three of four possibilities covered for user defined classes.

**Edit:** A correction: Technically, a user-defined class [could have *neither*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46575174/if-an-object-doesnt-have-dict-does-its-class-must-have-a-slots-att#comment80104405_46575174); the class would be defined with `__slots__`, but have it deleted after definition time (the machinery that sets up the type doesn't require `__slots__` to persist after the class definition finishes). No sane person should do this, and it could have undesirable side-effects (full behavior untested), but it's possible.

For built-in types, at least in the CPython reference interpreter, they're *extremely* unlikely to have `__slots__` (if they did, it would be to simulate a user-defined class, defining it doesn't actually *do* anything useful). A built-in type typically stores its attributes as raw C level values and pointers on a C level struct, optionally with explicitly created descriptors or accessor methods, which eliminates the purpose of `__slots__`, which are just a convenient limited purpose equivalent of such struct games for user defined classes. `__dict__` is opt-in for built-in types, not on by default (though the opt-in process is fairly easy; you need to put a `PyObject*` entry somewhere in the struct and provide the offset to it in the type definition).

To be clear, `__dict__` need not appear on the *class* for it to appear on its *instances*; `__slots__` is class level, and can suppress the `__dict__` on the *instance*, but has no effect on whether the class itself has a `__dict__`; user defined *classes* always have `__dict__`, but their instances won't if you're careful to use `__slots__` appropriately.

So in short:

(Sane) User defined classes have at least one of `__dict__` (on the instances) or `__slots__` (on the class), and can have both. Insane user defined classes *could* have neither, but only a deranged developer would do it.

Built-in classes often have neither, *may* provide `__dict__`, and almost never provide `__slots__` as it is pointless for them.

Examples:

```
# Class has __slots__, instances don't have __dict__
class DictLess:
    __slots__ = ()

# Instances have __dict__, class lacks __slots__
class DictOnly:
    pass

# Class has __slots__, instances have __dict__ because __slots__ declares it
class SlottedDict:
    __slots__ = '__dict__',

# Class has __slots__ without __dict__ slot, instances have it anyway from unslotted parent
class DictFromParent(DictOnly):
    __slots__ = ()

# Complete insanity: __slots__ takes effect at class definition time, but can
# be deleted later, without changing the class behavior:
class NoSlotNoDict:
    __slots__ = ()
del NoSlotNoDict.__slots__
# Instances have no __dict__, class has no __slots__ but acts like it does
# (the machinery to make it slotted isn't undone by deleting __slots__)
# Please, please don't actually do this

# Built-in type without instance __dict__ or class defined __slots__:
int().__dict__  # Raises AttributeError
int.__slots__   # Also raises AttributeError

# Built-in type that opts in to __dict__ on instances:
import functools
functools.partial(int).__dict__ # Works fine
functools.partial.__slots__ # Raises AttributeError
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to tell if an object has `__dict__` merely from its class?
If its class has `__slots__`, then it doesn't have `__dict__`.
If its class doesn't have `__slots__`, how can I tell if it has `__dict__` or not?

Comment: @Tim: `hasattr(obj, '__dict__')`?

Comment: @Tim: A class that has `__slots__` can still have `__dict__` (if it includes `'__dict__'` as a slot name, or a parent class didn't define `__slots__`). If the class doesn't have `__slots__`, it could be a built-in type without `__dict__`, or a user defined class with a `__dict__`. Make an instance, check it for `__dict__`, that's the reliable way.

Comment: by "A class that has `__slots__` can still have `__dict__`", do you mean  "if a class has `__slots__`, its instances can still have `__dict__`" or  "if a class has `__slots__`, the class itself can still have `__dict__`" ?

Comment: @Tim: User defined classes themselves *always* have a `__dict__`; you can suppress it on the instances with `__slots__`.

Comment: Note: the closest you can come to "is this a python or a C type" is testing `__flags__ & (1 << 9)`

Comment: @o11c: And I'm not sure that's a documented guarantee even for CPython, let alone the various alternate interpreters.

Comment: Thanks. (1) ["To support arbitrary attribute assignment, an object needs a `__dict__`"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1529099). So is it correct that `__dict__` as an attribute of a class or instance is used for storing user defined attributes of the class or instance?  (2) What do you mean by "Built-in classes often have neither, may provide `__dict__`" and "`__dict__` is opt-in for built-in types"? Is `__dict__` for a builtin class used for storing user-defined attributes?

Comment: To #1: Yes, unless the attributes are slotted, in which case they're not stored in `__dict__`. To #2. Exactly what I said. Built-ins can, but almost never do, use `__dict__` to store instance attributes. When they provide `__dict__`, it's usually to allow (for whatever reason) the user to add additional arbitrary attributes to instances of the class.

Comment: For example, `functools.partial` didn't have to provide `__dict__`, and doesn't use it itself (it [stores all the stuff it actually uses in top-level pointers in the C struct](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Modules/_functoolsmodule.c#L14)), but it provides it (and makes sure it survives pickling and unpickling), probably because regular functions allow you to set arbitrary additional attributes, and they wanted it to behave like a normal function object (since it wraps functions and otherwise behaves like one).

Comment: Thanks. `object` is a builtin class, but `object.__dict__` is not empty by default,.   `__dict__` is meant to store user-defined attributes, while `object.__dict__`  stores builtin attributes of `object`?

Comment: Nothing mandates that *only* user defined stuff go in `__dict__`. Classes have `__dict__`, always, but if you actually look at the `__dict__` for `object`, it's mostly just a bunch of slot wrappers; descriptors that provide a Python-level names for the C level function pointers associated with the type (which are dynamically defined, because not all slots are populated on each type). In any event, you're trying to draw hard & fast lines that don't exist. `__dict__` is a simple, convenient way to store arbitrary attributes. Nothing *requires* that it only be used for user specified attributes.

Comment: As it happens, it looks like `type` subclasses (which are what classes themselves are instances of) *can't* define non-empty `__slots__` (and non-empty `__slots__` doesn't actually block `__dict__`), possibly due to optimization related concerns for super class lookups and the like, possibly because trying to do so would interfere with the automatically generated attributes Python creates for classes; for classes, the only place they have to store arbitrary data is `__dict__`, thus the observed behavior.

Comment: "no sane person should do this" well guess what they did it :P look at ClientUser in discord,py

Comment: @JohnSohn: I don't see anything obviously weird there. They define `__slots__` and never delete them. Only slightly weird thing they do is actually *use* `__slots__` programmatically in other contexts (to make a mix-in named `_RawReprMixin` that defines `__repr__` without naming all the attributes explicitly by relying on the `__slots__` of the class), and that's only lightly weird (it's a brittle hack that only works for the most derived subclass, ignoring the `__slots__` of the parent classes).

Comment: A user-defined class could also be created by directly using `type`.