# Accessing dictionary keys using dot(.)

Tags: python

I can not access the dictionary keys with dot(.) but when I define a class that inherits from dict, I can access its keys using dot(.). Can anybody explain it?

So, when I run this code:

```
d = {'first_key':1, 'second_key':2}
d.first_key
```

I get this error:

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'first_key'
```

but when I run this:

```
class DotDict(dict):
    pass
d = DotDict()
d.first_key = 1
d.second_key = 2
print(d.first_key)
print(d.second_key)
```

I get this:

```
1
2
```

Comment: Because at that point you're just creating member variables and not necessary adding to the dictionary (in the second example)

Comment: You have to add certain magic methods to get that functionality: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352181/how-to-use-a-dot-to-access-members-of-dictionary

Comment: For example, in the second case, if you try to do `d['first_key']`, you will get a KeyError

Comment: You should test your example without inheriting from `dict`.

Comment: This question doesn't deserve all these downvotes. It is properly formulated. And just because something might be obvious for someone, doesn't mean it is for someone else. OP even provided their exploration about the problem

Comment: Please reserve downvotes/upvotes for the quality/formatting of questions and not based on the simplicity/obviousness of the content/mistakes

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984647/accessing-dict-keys-like-an-attribute

Comment: Also see this question, about `AttributeError` for dict: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529002/cant-set-attributes-of-object-class

Comment: Are you coming from a JavaScript background? Python dictionaries may look like JS Objects but they aren't equivalent

Comment: There are many reasons to not use the "dot-as-dict-entry-getter" model in Python. Example: what if the data has a key like `'len'` or `'get'` or another method name on your class? This would break code that uses those methods. Example: how would you access keys that aren't valid Python names like `1` or `dash-name`? You'd have to mix dot and `[]` notation, ick. It's best to use the existing language construct. Don't try to recreate JavaScript syntax in Python.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for your consideration @sshashank124

Comment: Thanks @KlausD.. Your comment helped me.

Comment: Thanks for your help @PM2Ring

Comment: Thanks @soon. I appreciate your help.

Comment: No, I’m not. Thanks for your tips @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Your comments helped me. Thanks @ChrisJohnson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By applying your example

```
class DotDict(dict):
    pass

d = DotDict()
d.first_key = 1
d.second_key = 2
print(d.first_key)
print(d.second_key)
```

you set instance parameters `first_key` and `second_key` to your `DotDict` class but not to the dictionary itself. You can see this, if you just put your dictionary content to the screen:

```
In [5]: d
Out[5]: {}
```

So, it is just an empty dict. You may access dictionaries the common way:

```
In [1]: d={}

In [2]: d['first'] = 'foo'

In [3]: d['second'] = 'bar'

In [4]: d
Out[4]: {'first': 'foo', 'second': 'bar'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 2):

in the first case, you are creating keys and values belonging to a dictionary object. while in the second, you are creating attributes of a class which has nothing to do with the dictionary parent class you inherited.

Comment: That is a precious point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the `dict` elements need to access through `keys`.

```
d['first_key']
```

Output:

```
1
```

If you want to access using (.) then use `get`.

Using `get` you can get the required value

```
d = {'first_key':1, 'second_key':2}
print(d.get('first_key'))
```

Output:

```
1
```

With respect to `class` you are accessing the attributes of `class`. So you will have to access using (.)

Comment: @pythinker: This works well. I tested it

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @pythinker: So it worked. That's great. Please confirm the answer so that it will help for others